# "HTTP Request Failed" and "Trying to Get Property of Non-Object" errors

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get a YouTube channel's video views and it works perfect on localhost but I'm getting this error on my public web server:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={MY YOUTUBE USER ID}&fields=items%2Fstatistics&key={MY API KEY}): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /var/www/*****.net/public_html/dashboard/inc/youtube-api.php on line 9 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/*****.net/public_html/dashboard/inc/youtube-api.php on line 10 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/*****.net/public_html/dashboard/inc/youtube-api.php on line 10 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/*****./public_html/dashboard/inc/youtube-api.php on line 10
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function getYouTubeStats($stat)
{
$channel = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={my youtube user id}&fields=items%2Fstatistics&key={MY API KEY}"));
return $channel->items[0]->statistics->videoCount;
}

echo getYouTubeStats($stat = null);

?>
```

Comment: your f_g_c call failed, and since your code assumes that nothing could ever fail, you took the boolean false from f_g_c and tried to json_decode it, producing further failures... Note that the error message says it's a 403 - google is DENYING you access to that url.

Comment: try to use true parameter with json_decode like this :

json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={my youtube user id}&fields=items%2Fstatistics&key={MY API KEY}"),TRUE);

Comment: @Opetmar: useless, since the http request itself is failing. there's nothing to decode, so changing decode modes is utterly pointless.

Comment: @Marc B, could you think of any reason for the HTTP request failing? I've allowed all IPV4 addresses on the server to use my API key so that shouldn't be it.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah i just realized that .

Comment: @MiguelRenaud-Nolte Well i thought you said that you solved it . but anyway try to use CURL instead of  file_get_contents.

Comment: @Opetmar the cURL solved the HTTP request error but I still get an error at "return $channel->items[0]->statistics->videoCount;" saying "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: @MiguelRenaud-Nolte
try to print_r the CURL response , does it output a correct response ?

Comment: Ah thanks. It printed out something about my server IP being denied. Atleast I know the problem. For some reason Google isn't recognizing/updating the allowed IP list for the API key.

Comment: could you post the error message ..

Comment: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "ipRefererBlocked", "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.", "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com" } ], "code": 403, "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Con...

Comment: well , try to regenerate the api key and use it instead ... if it didn't work try to create a new project , enable youtube api then use it's api key .

Comment: @opetmar hmm It's weird I can't figure out the problem. I've tried creating a new project and such but it still doesn't work

Comment: @MiguelRenaud-Nolte
well that's weird .. are you sure that you are allowed access to all IP's by leaving the field empty in google console in the new created project ?

Comment: @opetmar It works now. I guess the allowed IP list just takes a long time to update..